# Simple PHP login session without database

Tags: php, session, authentication, membership

I'm looking to produce a simple login session script, this does not have to be very secure and I was hoping to do it without the need for a database. Basically I want to give people invites to the webpage and they can only access it with the username and password on the invite, therefore I require more than one login. I would also like to display a message upon successful login with something like "Welcome *username*."

I found the code below which seems to do the job well but how can I adjust it to hide the form after login?

```
<?php
session_start();

$userinfo = array(
                'user1'=>'password1',
                'user2'=>'password2'
                );

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = '';
    header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    }else {
        //Invalid Login
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if($_SESSION['username']): ?>
            <p>You are logged in as <?=$_SESSION['username']?></p>
            <p><a href="?logout=1">Logout</a></p>
        <?php endif; ?>
        <form name="login" action="" method="post">
            Username:  <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
            Password:  <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: so what's not happening here and was the session started? any errors also?

Comment: *"I found the code below which seems to do the job well but how can I adjust it to hide the form after login?"* - Oh, so it works then, to which "that" is the real question, correct?

Comment: Hi Fred. The login form is still displaying after the user has logged in successfully, I would like this only to appear if they are not logged in. I don't have any errors other than that.

Comment: you have not specify any conditional statement for your login form.

Comment: many ways to do this; css hide, wrap the form in an echo assigned to a session variable all in a conditional statement; add an exit... etc.

Comment: you should redirect/open another page like welcome.php where you should check that `if(isset($_POST['username']) && $_POST['username'])` to access only logged in user, and vice versa you put a one like code in login.php to access only logged out user.

Comment: Many thanks. I do like the idea of having a separate welcome page after login with a message like "Welcome _username_."

Answer (score 1):

Just put your form in a condition

```
if(empty($_SESSION['username'])){
   // your html form here
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this:

```
<?php
session_start();

$userinfo = array(
                'user1'=>'password1',
                'user2'=>'password2'
                );

if(isset($_GET['logout'])) {
    $_SESSION['username'] = '';
    header('Location:  ' . $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}

if(isset($_POST['username'])) {
    if($userinfo[$_POST['username']] == $_POST['password']) {
        $_SESSION['username'] = $_POST['username'];
    }else {
        //Invalid Login
    }
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Login</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <?php if($_SESSION['username']): ?>
            <p>You are logged in as <?=$_SESSION['username']?></p>
            <p><a href="?logout=1">Logout</a></p>
        <?php else: ?>
        <form name="login" action="" method="post">
            Username:  <input type="text" name="username" value="" /><br />
            Password:  <input type="password" name="password" value="" /><br />
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
        </form>
    <?php endif; ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
     {
          $_SESSION['username'] = '';
          header('Location: /');
     }
```

to

```
if(isset($_GET['logout']))
     {
          Session_destroy();
          header('Location: /');
     }
```

If you don't kill/destroy session, you will have a big problem.